# Prime Numbers in Python

Tags: python, primes

I was trying to write a program that would display the prime numbers between 2 and 200.

This is the program that i wrote.

```
liste = [ ]
liste.append(2)
liste = [2]

for primeCandidate in range (2,10):
    isPrime = True
    for divisor in range (2,primeCandidate):
        if primeCandidate % divisor == 0:
            isPrime = False
            break
        if isPrime:
            liste.append(primeCandidate)
            print(liste)
```

But I always get a wrong output. And I couldn't find my mistakes. Can you help me finding my mistakes?

Comment: ****for primeCandidate in range (2,200):

Comment: What output are you getting? Also, note that it's unnecessary to test _every_ value from 2 to the primeCandidate. You only need to test odd integers <= sqrt(primeCandidate).

Comment: The wrong output i get is : [2, 3]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 3, 5, 5]
[2, 3, 5, 5, 5]
[2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7]
[2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7]
[2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7]
[2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7]
[2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
[2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9]

Comment: Look Ma, one line!  `[x for x in xrange(2,200) if all(x % n for n in xrange(2,x))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things leap out:

(1) You don't need to set liste to [2] at the start; your primeCandidate loop includes 2, so you'll get 2 twice if you do.

(2) Your "if isPrime" is one level too deep.  You can only trust isPrime after you've checked the candidate divisors.  (Well, you're actually checking more than you need, but that's only an efficiency issue, not a bug.)  To be specific:

```
liste = []
for primeCandidate in range (2,100):
    isPrime = True
    for divisor in range (2,primeCandidate):
        if primeCandidate % divisor == 0:
            isPrime = False
            break
    if isPrime:
        liste.append(primeCandidate)
        print(liste)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Now the output is correct. The only problem is the output looks like this

[2]
[2, 3]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 3, 5, 7]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19] And so on till 97. 

The output i want is : [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97] How can i get this ?

Comment: @EkremIpek: Again, move the `print(liste)` out two levels so that it lines up with the first `for`. You only want to print the list once after you have checked all the candidates.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solved this problem. I've started programming last week. Thats why im making that silly mistakes :D

Answer (score 1):

```
from math import sqrt


def isPrime(num) :
    if num in [2,  3 ] : return True
    elif num < 2: return False 
    for i in [2]  +  range(3, int(sqrt(num)),  2) :
        if not num % i: return False 
    return True 

liste = [i for i in range(2,  201) if isPrime(i)]
```

Note: In Python 3.x, `range()` returns a `range` object, not a `list`, therefore you would have to change

```
for i in [2] + range(3, int(sqrt(num)), 2):
```

to

```
for i in [2] + list(range(3, int(sqrt(num)), 2)):
```

to avoid the resulting `TypeError`.

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "range") to list

Comment: @groovehunter: In Python 3.x, `range()` returns a `range` object, whereas in Python 2, `range()` returns a list. I've added a note in my answer as well.